# vicon with ROS INDIGO

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have recently upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 meaning an upgrade from ROS fuerte to ROS indigo. Unfortunately, the vicon_bridge package is failing to compile. One of the ‘tf_cb_' error messages is

../../vicon_bridge/src/tf_distort.cpp:154:6: error: ‘tf_cb_’ was not declared in this scope
if(tf_cb_.connected())

Is there a fix for this problem? Are there any plans getting vicon_bridge to work with ROS indigo? If not, are there alternative packages to vicon_bridge that can get vicon messages into 'tf' message type?

Regards,
Moses.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199701/vicon-with-ros-indigo/) by [dnovichman](https://answers.ros.org/users/21151/dnovichman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-12-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `vicon_bridge` in the [ethz-asl/vicon_bridge](https://github.com/ethz-asl/vicon_bridge.git) repository (which seems like a stand-alone repository for just `vicon_bridge`, which was originally [here](https://github.com/ethz-asl/ros-drivers)) compiles for me under Indigo.

Note: I have not tested whether it actually *works* (but I assume it does).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dnovichman](https://answers.ros.org/users/21151/dnovichman/) on 2014-12-18**:
Thanks. I can confirm to you that I have compiled and tested the latest vicon_bridge and it worked.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-12-19**:
@dnovichman: I've converted your post to a comment, please only use answers for actual answers.

**Comment by [101010](https://answers.ros.org/users/3108/101010/) on 2015-01-14**:
FYI - Thanks for the link however, the ROS site does not have the most recent catkinized vicon_bridge node link, this is why I could not find it.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-01-14**:
Please don't take my answer on [catkin 'ized' Vicon Package](http://answers.ros.org/question/200682/catkin-ized-vicon-package/) as criticism, I'm merely trying to avoid posting the same information multiple times by refering people to older answers.